# JOLT Transformation needed

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to use JOLT to split an array of Tags into multiple Tags based on an attribute.

here is input and expected output

Input json

```
{
  "student": [
    {
      "student_name": "jone",
      "age": 12,
      "class": "Seven",
      "grade": "first-class"
    },
    {
      "student_name": "jack",
      "age": 13,
      "class": "Eight",
      "grade": "first-class"
    },
    {
      "student_name": "rosy",
      "age": 13,
      "class": "Eight",
      "grade": "second-class"
    }
  ]
}
```

expected output as like

```
{
  "jone": {
    "student_name": "jone",
    "age": 12,
    "class": "Seven",
    "grade": "first-class"
  },
  "jack": {
    "student_name": "jack",
    "age": 13,
    "class": "Eight",
    "grade": "first-class"
  },
  "rosy": {
    "student_name": "rosy",
    "age": 13,
    "class": "Eight",
    "grade": "second-class"
  }
}
```

please help me on the Jolt transformation. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks for the response. i got the desired output. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can put asterisk(`"*"`) key, nested within `"student"` key, in order to produce indexes for the respective members, along with the `"@(1,student_name)"` ( **or** *better* `"@(1,&2_name)"` ) value as the innermost element for a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "student": {
        "*": {
          "@": "@(1,&2_name)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```